# Передача строки матрицы в функцию

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, матрицы

В чём у меня заключается ошибка передачи строки матрицы в функцию?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 3

int GetSum(int *a[n]){
    int s=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%i",a[i]);
        s += a[i];
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    int a[n][n]={{6,8,-6},{5,0,1},{7,5,7}};
    int s[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        s[i] = GetSum(&a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Компилировать пробовали? Что непонятно в сообщениях компилятора? А так, в `GetSum()` вы описали аргумент как массив из `n` указателей. Напишите просто `GetSum (int a[n])`. И тогда вызывайте ее, передавая адрес первого элемента строки -- `s[i] = GetSum(&a[i][0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка матрицы — массив целых, а вы параметром функции сделали массив указателей:

1. `int GetSum(int *a[n])` звёздочка лишняя;
2. `s[i] = GetSum(&a[i]);` а здесь — аперсанд (&).

```
int GetSum(int a[n])
...
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    s[i] = GetSum(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Это у меня будет передаваться указатель на массив, правильно?

Comment: Будет передоваться указатель на первый элемент массива, а не указатель на массив

Comment: А в моём случае передавался "указатель на массив"?

Comment: Передавали "массив указателей".